Is there an explanation to the following Typescript snippet not correctly inferring the type?
In the following scenario, should typescript not properly infer that if we are in the third case then item.id is not null ?
Is there a breach in my understanding, or some bug or edge case from ts ?
export const Type = [
    "TypeA",
    "TypeB",
    "TypeC"
] as const
export type Type = typeof Type[number]

type Item = {
    id: string | null,
    type: Type
}

function stringFunction(some_string: string) {
    console.log(some_string)
}
function test(item: Item) {
    if (!item.id && item.type === Type[2]) return

    switch (item.type) {
        case 'TypeA':
            break;
        case 'TypeB':
            break;
        case 'TypeC':
            // By uncommenting the following line, the type is correctly inferred in the third case
            // But why is it needed ? A case analysis should suffice to know we have a non null item.id
            // if (!item.id ) return
            stringFunction(item.id)
            break;
    }
}


Playground Link

It's a design limitation of TS; it is intractable for TS to either simulate every possible way your code could be run or to be able to make higher order logical inferences from the structure of your code.  The support TS has for narrowing is very specific to particular idiomatic JS patterns and cannot be generalized. See ms/TS#52822 and the issues linked within for more info. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer; if not, what's missing?

Yes, the link you provided seems to be a very close match of my issue. You answered perfectly.

See microsoft/TypeScript#52822 for an authoritative answer to this question.
The support TypeScript has for narrowing is limited to some specific idiomatic patterns in JavaScript. It works well when the relationships you are tracking can be described in terms of each variable or property independently. Once you start needing to care about sets of variables or properties, it stops being feasible for the compiler.  In your case, you are trying to "tie" the state of item.id to the state of item.type. But in order to notice that, TypeScript would either have to simulate running the program for every possible set of inputs, which is intractable; or it would have to store state information about every combination of expressions that appears in the program, which is intractable; or it would have to have human-level intelligence to abstract over your code to derive invariants on the fly, which is... well, we don't know how to write a compiler that does that.
It seems easy enough for a pair of properties with only a few possible values for each, but the slope to intractability is slippery, and putting up a barrier a little way down the slope is confusing because then the behavior is discontinuous (e.g., "why did this code work when Type had three elements but break when it has four?")  See @RyanCavanaugh's Twitter thread on incompleteness for a word from the TS team dev lead.
Your best bet in cases like this is to refactor so that the state you care about is held in a single variable or property. For your example code you would want the check to be closer to where it needs to be enforced, in a place which is logically identical to !item.id && item.type === "TypeC", such as the line you commented out:
function test(item: Item) {
    switch (item.type) {
        case 'TypeA':
            break;
        case 'TypeB':
            break;
        case 'TypeC':
            if (!item.id) return
            stringFunction(item.id)
            break;
    }
}

For real-world code it's usually possible to refactor in such a way. But in situations where it isn't, you'll have to just put up with TypeScript's lack of ability to track these things, and use something like a type assertion (e.g., item.id! or item.id as string) to make progress.
Playground link to code
